# split a string on semicolons taking into account strings and escaped quotes or semicolons

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all, preg-split

I'm still trying to figure out a way to take into account escaped quotes like `"test\";nosplit"` or `'test\';nosplit'`

So far I have something like this:

```
preg_split('#(^;)|(;$)|(?<!["\'\\]);#', $str_to_split);
```

But it's not even working on something as simple as: `test; 1; 2; '34;34'; wtvr`

I want it to split on these:

```
    v  v  v        v
test; 1; 2; '34;34'; wtvr

    v  v v            v
test; 1;2; '34\'34;34'; wtvr 

    v  v v            v
test; 1;2; "34\"34;34"; wtvr

    v  v v            v
test; 1;2; '34\"34;34'; wtvr 

    v  v v            v
test; 1;2; "34\'34;34"; wtvr

    v  v v                    v
test; 1;2; "3 4 \' 3  4 ; 3 4"; wtvr
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: Not sure if this is "cheating" but I would first protect semicolons in quotes, then split normally, and finally put them back.

Comment: @Floris How do you find semicolons that are only in quotes?

Comment: `'[^\]\'.*;.*[^\]\''` should do it?

Comment: @Floris Are you forgetting about `test; 1;2; '34\\'34;34'; wtvr` and `test; 1;2; '34\\\'34;34'; wtvr`

Comment: Yes I did forget about that case...

Answer (score 0):

Why not use [`str_getcsv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php)?

var_dump(str_getcsv("test; 1; 2; '34;34'; wtvr",";","'"));

http://ideone.com/JoFkr7#

Comment: This only works if all of the strings are single quotes, but I want to be able to use double too.

Comment: Hmm...ok, but it seems like you're reinventing CSV, but with different rules. :)